# select * from table1 where user_id in(select id from users where name like '%name%')

Tags: mysql, laravel

hello i need a help please,

how can i write this query in Laravel

```
select * from table1 where user_id in(select id from users where name like '%name%')
```

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways.

```
$data = Db::table('table1')
    ->join('users', 'table1.user_id', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.name', 'like', '%name%')
    ->get();
```